# dropdown dependent pick list

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

---

I have three dependent dropdowns working, fourth is failing, error for range on function restrict cell to list; example below . from the pick list the first three work and change, my fourth, last choice does not restrict data to the previous choice.

```
  function restrictCellToList(cellString, list) {
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellString);
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list,       true).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
cell.setValue(list[0]);
```

}

```
  function initializeTrims() {
var selectedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var selectedMake = selectedCell.getValue();
var selectedModel = selectedCell.getValue();
var selectedYear = selectedCell.getValue();
var selectedTrim = selectedCell.getValue();

var cars_raw =    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_raw");
Logger.log("You have selected %s", selectedYear);

var trims = [];  
var carData = getCarData();
for (var i = 0; i < carData.length; i++) {
  var row = carData[i];
  var make = row[0];
  var model = row[1];
  var year = row[2];
  var trim = row[3];
  if (year == "") {
    continue;
   }
  if (year == selectedYear && trims.indexOf(trim) == -1) {
    trims.push(trim);
  }
}

 restrictCellToList("D2", trims);

 Logger.log("Trims: %s", trims);
```

}

Comment: var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellstring);   //this works three times but fails on the fourth and my last pick list does not update RANGE NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function initializeTrims() {
var selectedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var selectedMake = selectedCell.getValue();
var selectedModel = selectedCell.getValue();
var selectedYear = selectedCell.getValue();
var selectedTrim = selectedCell.getValue();
// this line was failing because the variables where looping           indefinitely I fixed it by changing to get range 

var selectedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var selectedMake = ss.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var selectedModel = ss.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var selectedYear = ss.getRange(2, 3).getValue();
  var cars_raw =       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_raw");
```